# Is there any way to intercept and modify build-in Class's static method?

Tags: ecmascript-6

With `instanceof`, we can do this:

```js
new Number(1) instanceof Number           // true
```

But we can't do this:

```js
1 instanceof Number                       // false
```

Since ES6 provide `[Symbol.hasInstance]` for us, we can use it to create a new class in order to make `instanceof` could check for primitive value. For example:

```js
class MyNumber {
    static [Symbol.hasInstance](x){
        return typeof(x) === 'object'? x instanceof Number:typeof(x) === 'number'
    }
}
const a = 1
const b = new Number(1)
a instanceof MyNumber                 // true
b instanceof MyNumber                 // true
```

However, can we just intercept and modify build-in Class's static method (`Number[Symbol.hasInsatnce]` in this case) instead of creating another new class (`MyNumber` in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are in fact functions. So `Object.defineProperty` on `Number` will do it.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number, Symbol.hasInstance, {
  value: function(x) {
    return typeof(x) === 'object' ? x instanceof Number : typeof(x) === 'number'
  }
});

console.log(1 instanceof Number);
```